# Restaurar base de datos SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Estoy tratando de restaurar una base de datos en sql server, con dos archivos.

1. Es el bkp full de la base de datos
2. Es el diferencial

Para el cual uso el siguiente script

```
--prueba RESTORE completo diferencial
RESTORE DATABASE ANDROMEDA
  FROM DISK='G:\BackupInstanciaSDC\BackupCompletos\E2I_AG_FULL_01102019_000007.BAK'
  WITH REPLACE, NORECOVERY,
  MOVE N'E2I_AG' TO N'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SDC\MSSQL\DATA\ANDROMEDA.mdf',  
  MOVE N'E2I_AG_log' TO N'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SDC\MSSQL\DATA\ANDROMEDA_log.ldf'

  GO
  RESTORE DATABASE ANDROMEDA
  FROM DISK='G:\BackupInstanciaSDC\BackupDiferenciales\E2I_AG_DIFF_01102019_140003.BAK'
  WITH NORECOVERY
  GO
  RESTORE DATABASE ANDROMEDA WITH RECOVERY
  GO
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He recorrido muchos blogs pero al parecer este error no es muy común, ¿alguien mas se ha topado con este o sabe que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Intenta restaurar el diferencial con las condiciones: `WITH FILE = 2,   NORECOVERY; `

Comment: @reekeecast Gracias por responder, usando tu linea de código me cambia el error ya me muestra : `Mens. 3241, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 8
La familia de medios del dispositivo 'G:\BackupInstanciaSDC\BackupDiferenciales\E2I_AG_DIFF_01102019_140003.BAK' no está formada correctamente.`

Comment: Entiendo que ese mensaje puede ser 2 cosas: **1)** Las versiones de SQL Server difieren (el original es mas nuevo que donde quieres restaurar) o bien **2)** el archivo backup si está corrupto y es necesario generarlo de nuevo.